# NSDateFormatter incorrect date conversion

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using NSDateFormatter, to convert NSString to NSDate.

For e.g if my NSString value is **Jun 24,2015** Then it is getting converted as **2015-06-23 18:30:00 +0000**, which is incorrect.

It should be "24" instead of "23".

I am using below code to convert.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy"];
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter dateFromString:strDate]);
```

Please help me to figure out the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might help you out. Add the following code.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `NSDateFormatter` takes the value as local Date formate( IST, GMT +5:30) and then convert it to GMT. It take your value as 00:00 am, 24 june 2015 and convert it as according to GMT 18:30 23 june 2015 means 5 hours and 30 minutes before the actual time so just simply add

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add line of `NSTimeZone` :

```
   NSString *dateString = @"Jun 24,2015";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy "];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

Comment: There is no difference between the code i am using and you suggested.

Comment: see my updated answer its perfect work @ArvinderSingh